# How to only estimate neonatal mortality using syncmrates in Stata?

Tags: variables, binary, command, stata, readstata13

How to only estimate neonatal mortality (nmr) using `syncmrates` in Stata? How to get the output that is nmr as binary variable using `syncmrates`?

I can get under 5 mortatlity rates, imr, nmr and pmr using `syncmrates` command. However I need only nmr as it is my main outcome variable and I need it in a binary form to carry out regression.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the program author?